# ubuntu installation done; but unable to start any program

Tags: system-installation

I just installed ubuntu on my pc. I completely removed xp. The installation seems to be ok. I have the ubuntu start monitor but when I move the mouse onto a program item I can´t start any program by doubleclicking it. There is no reaction at all.

I don´t understand where the problem is.

Guido

---

Yes, none of the icons respond to a left click or double click.

Comment: Can you give us an example? If you left click (once) one the folder icon on the left (on the unity launchbar), nothing happens?

Comment: @hakermania The OP responded in an answer. I have edited the response into the question.